# Unable to get href of an <a> with XPath despite being able to get other attributes

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xhtml

Given:

```
<a href="http://british-business-bank.co.uk/?p=6419" class="cta"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>Senior Project Manager – Northern Powerhouse Investment Fund</a>
```

This XPath correcty returns this anchor.

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Project')]
```

And if I want to get its `class` attribute, the following XPath works:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Project')]/@class
```

I would expect that getting attribute `href` would involve something similar, yet:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Project')]/@href
```

doesn't return anything (at least not in the Console of Chrome Dev Tools). Why not?

Comment: Yes, the `href` attribute works exactly the same, I cannot reproduce your issue. If `//a[contains(text(), 'Project')]/@class` works while `//a[contains(text(), 'Project')]/@href` does not and you are sure that the HTML source has this attribute, this is a serious bug that you should consider to report.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I am not going crazy. I guess it's over to other browser extensions for verifying my XPaths.

Comment: In most cases, though, the users are at fault - including myself. It is not yet proven that the Chrome Dev Tools are buggy. Please provide a complete HTML sample and show what exactly you enter into the console, together with the browser and version information. Help on compiling this sample: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.